# Can Ubuntu be installed from a USB memory stick with bad blocks (or clusters) on it?

Tags: boot, usb, software-installation, media, data-corruption

I have spent a few days trying to install Ubuntu from a USB memory stick with at least one bad block (or Cluster) on it.

I have tried formatting it from an existing Ubuntu machine and from Windows using various means and file/system formats including Rufus.   It seems that though the formatter can be set to check the memory stick for bad blocks and exclude them, in the end the media creator still seems to write to the bad blocks blindly, creating a memory stick with corrupt data on it. I have tried this now with a couple of old memory sticks with bad blocks on them and the result is the same, regardless of what I try.

However, using a perfect USB memory stick with no bad blocks on it works first time every time.  Am I missing an option or setting somewhere? Alternatively can the formatter that detects the bad blocks be set to warn that the media will be corrupt if the creation process is continued and ask the user if they wish to continue?

Answer (score 2):

I think most tools to create a USB drive assume that the USB memory stick is good. At least this is the case with mkusb (and obviously also with the tools that you have been trying to use).

***1. Wipe the whole device*** might help if the memory cells can be re-allocated after wiping.

You could try to 'wipe the whole device' with [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb), and after that try with your tool(s) to create a USB install system in the memory stick again. (The re-allocation process is nothing that we can manage. There is an internal processor in the USB memory stick, and it would do it automatically, if it can.)

***2. ext4***

An alternative is to create a partition with the **ext4** file system in the memory stick, and to run the following command in linux in order to mark the bad clusters, so that the file system can avoid using them.

```
sudo e2fsck -cf /dev/sdxy
```

where x is the drive letter (a or b or c ...) and y is the partition number (1 or 2 or 3 ...). In your case it might be /dev/sdb1, the second drive's first partition. If this operation succeeds, you will get a USB memory stick, that can be used for storage by linux systems. It will also be possible to install Ubuntu into it (installed like into an internal drive). But this is not a USB install drive, that can install Ubuntu into another system.

***3. NTFS***

Another alternative would be to create a partition with the **NTFS** file system in the memory stick, and to run the following command in Windows in order to mark the bad clusters, so that the file system can avoid using them.

```
chkdsk /r X:
```

where X: is the drive letter (volume letter) for the target partition as seen from Windows. If this operation succeeds, you will get a USB memory stick, that can be used for storage by linux systems and Windows systems, but it does not help installers, that need a FAT32 file system.

***4. FAT32 might fix it all the way in this particular case***

Finally you can create a partition with the **FAT32** file system in the memory stick, and to run the following command in Windows in order to mark the bad clusters, so that the file system can avoid using them.

```
chkdsk /r X:
```

where X: is the drive letter (volume letter) for the target partition as seen from Windows. If this operation succeeds, you will get a USB memory stick, that can be used for storage by linux systems and Windows systems, and it would help installers, that use a previously created FAT32 file system, for example ***Unetbootin***. So this might be possible for you, if the problem is 'only' some bad sector in the USB memory stick alias pendrive.

***5. See the following link for more details,***

[Repair the partition table and file system of a pendrive](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13409986#post13409986)

Answer (score -1):

Usually on the boot menu you can do a verification of the CD media, but I'm not sure if the USB booting gives you the same option. The installers take an all or nothing approach to the validity of the installation medium, it's either valid or not.

You may be able to get `dd` to do what you want by identifying the bad blocks, try this:

https://sourceforge.net/p/smartmontools/mailman/attachment/771ef40c0706252135s2ff0f76ej1c913f9cc93b601d@mail.gmail.com/1/